# Auto load the name of the user you're replying to

Tags: feature-request, android-app, comment-replies, autocomplete

I would like to add the feature that's already available on the SE network: auto loading the name of the user you're replying to, so that if you write `@F`, it will suggest `@Fischer`.

I cannot see that feature on my Android device.

Comment: People voted to close as not reproducible. Maybe show a video of it happening? The auto-completion works for me.